# spring boot running but standalone tomcat not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services, tomcat, spring-boot

I am developing a spring boot web application(My first Application) and it works fine when I deploy it in the embedded tomcat server.But when I deploy it in the standalone Tomcat server it cannot accesss the database.I am using Rest WebService to pass the data to the front end and my url will be look like

```
http://localhost:8080/day_demand?day=3
```

But in my standalone server when I access
`http://localhost:8080/WebApp/day_demand?day=3` (WebApp is my project name)

The connection to the database is made by the below code:

```
private Connection connectToDatabaseOrDie()
  {
    Connection conn = null;
    try
    {
      Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
      String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/data_base";
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"user", "password");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(2);
    }
    return conn;
  }
private void populateListOfTopics(Connection conn, List<State> listOfBlogs,Timestamp start_time,Timestamp end_time,int zone_id)
  {
    try 
    {

        String sql= "SELECT * FROM public.table where time >= ? and time <= ?";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pstmt.setTimestamp(1,start_time);


        pstmt.setTimestamp(2,end_time);


        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();


      while ( rs.next() )
      {
          State blog = new State();

        blog.year = rs.getInt ("year");
        blog.month=rs.getInt ("month");
        blog.day  = rs.getInt ("day");
        blog.hour = rs.getInt ("hour");



        listOfBlogs.add(blog);
      }

      rs.close();
      pstmt.close();
      conn.close();
    }
    catch (SQLException se) {
      System.err.println("Threw a SQLException creating the list of state.");
      System.err.println(se.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Err");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

I cannot able to access the data.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the logs? Is it giving any specific error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@john

I have twisted your code as per my Database and im able to get the data from db.Im using mysql.

[image: connection Class ScreenShot]

[image: Calling Class ScreenShot]

Here is the code:

```
                @RestController
                public class PersonController {



                    @Autowired
                    private PersonRepository personRepository;

                    @RequestMapping(value = "/persons/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces={MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE},headers = "Accept=application/xml")
                    public ResponseEntity<?> getPersonDetails(@PathVariable Long id, final HttpServletRequest request)throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("Before");
                        ConnectionManager cm=new ConnectionManager();
                        Person personResponse=cm.populateListOfTopics();
                        System.out.println("personResponse"+personResponse);
                        return ResponseEntity.ok(personResponse);
                    }

                }
```

Connection Class:

```
                    import java.sql.Connection;
                    import java.sql.DriverManager;
                    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
                    import java.sql.ResultSet;
                    import java.sql.SQLException;
                    import java.sql.Timestamp;
                    import java.util.List;

                    public class ConnectionManager {

                    private Connection connectToDatabaseOrDie()
                      {
                        Connection conn = null;
                        try
                        {
                          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                          String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/master?createDatabaseIfNotExist=false";
                          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root", "mysql");
                        }
                        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
                        {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                          System.exit(1);
                        }
                        catch (SQLException e)
                        {
                          e.printStackTrace();
                          System.exit(2);
                        }
                        return conn;
                      }

                    public Person populateListOfTopics()
                      {
                         Person person=new Person();
                        try 
                        {
                            Connection conn = ConnectionManager.this.connectToDatabaseOrDie();
                            String sql= "SELECT *  FROM master.person WHERE ID = 1";
                            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                            ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

                          while (rs.next())
                          {
                            person.setFirst_name(rs.getString("FIRST_NAME"));

                          }

                          rs.close();
                          pstmt.close();
                          conn.close();
                        }
                        catch (SQLException se) {
                          System.err.println("Threw a SQLException creating the list of state.");
                          System.err.println(se.getMessage());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("Err");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        return person;
                      }


                    }
```

Comment: It was the postgresql driver dependency causing the problem.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the below steps:

```
1) In pom.xml file , make scope as provided for embedded server 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

     or

 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>

 2) In pom.xml file, make packaging as war

     <packaging>war</packaging>

 3)  Extend SpringBootServletInitializer class in your Application.class


            import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
            import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
            import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
            import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
            import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
            import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
            import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


            @SpringBootApplication
            @Configuration
            @ComponentScan
            @EnableAutoConfiguration

            public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{



               public static void main(String[] args) {
                  SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
               }

               @Override
               protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
                   return application.sources(Application.class);
               }

               private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;

            }



 4) Take  the war from target folder and deploy it to External tomcat 
  and start the server.You will see logs as below :
```

[image: Spring Boot Tomcat Server Logs]

[image: Spring Boot Tomcat Server Logs ..continued]

5) Hit the URL somewhat like below :

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringBootExamples-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/persons/1
```

SpringBootExamples-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT = Context path

Same as Extracted folder name in External Tomcat Server

Comment: The problem is the appplication runs in the standalone tomcat server but It cannot access the database.I get the error **http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin**

Comment: Can you please paste the code as to how you are connecting to Database ?